# Error: HTTP Error 400, The Request has errors. Firebase Firestore Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

While I run the command firebase deploy I get this error:

> i  deploying functions
>
> i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
>
> i  runtimeconfig: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
>
> ✔  runtimeconfig: all necessary APIs are enabled
>
> ✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
>
> i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
>
> i  functions: packaged functions (4.04 KB) for uploading
>
> ✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
>
> i  starting release process (may take several minutes)...
>
> i  functions: creating function followerNotification...
>
> ⚠  functions: failed to create function followerNotification
>
> ⚠  functions: HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors
>
> ⚠  functions: 1 function(s) failed to be deployed.
>
> Functions deploy had errors. To continue deploying other features (such as >database), run:
>      firebase deploy --except functions
>
> Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
>
> Having trouble? Try firebase deploy --help

Everything else works without problems. Only when I trying to make something with Firebase Firestore.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

This was happening to me too, then I realized that at the 2nd level, firestore only allows documents and not collections.

I was attempting to listen to this path:

```
/collection/document/{wildcard}
```

You can either do something like

```
/collection/{wildcard}
```

or

```
/collection/document/collection/{wildcard}
```

Comment: Okej, this cant be the answer since it does not matter how many levels you go. You can nest this as much as you want. Look at my answer

Comment: This message is still as cryptic in July 2021, including via the web editor for cloud functions. A combination of this answer and removing an errant slash from the path as suggested in adamduren's answer was the solution for me.

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem as well. In my case it was because my trigger path had a trailing slash in the document path.

So changing:

```
functions.firestore
  .document('some_path/{pushId}/')
```

To:

```
functions.firestore
  .document('some_path/{pushId}')
```

Fixed it it for me. It seems like this is caused by a variety of issues and the firebase cli does not do a good job at explaining the reasons why.

Answer (score 13):

For me none of the answers helped me. In the end I got a list of steps (from Google) to pinpoint the problem. If you run:

```
firebase --debug --only functions deploy
```

it will give a more detailed error-message, what was in my case:

```
HTTP RESPONSE BODY <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>EntityTooLarge</Code><Message>Your proposed upload is larger than the maximum object size specified in your Policy Document.</Message><Details>Content-length exceeds upper bound on range</Details></Error>
```

Comment: it helped.
I did not know maximum length of functions name is 63

Comment: This is the most versatile answer that can work for anyone encountering this error message, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Okej this is what you need to look at.

since you have

`exports.yourFunctionName = functions.firestore.document`

the thing you need to look at is the `.document`

Your path **MUST** point to a document and not to a collection.

so this will **not work** :

`/level1/{level1Id}/level2`  <- it points to a collection

this **will work** :

`/level1/{level1Id}/level2/{level2Id}`

cloud function will look for when a **document** has an **action**

Hope this will help anybody

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you only reference a collection and not a document like:

```
exports.myFunctionName = functions.firestore
      .document('users').onWrite((event) => {
        // ... Your code here
      });
```

You need to reference the document like:

```
exports.myFunctionName = functions.firestore
  .document('users/marie').onWrite((event) => {
    // ... Your code here
  });
```

You can also use a wildcard like:

```
exports.myFunctionName = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}').onWrite((event) => {
    // ... Your code here
  });
```

It's described in here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

Hope I could help

Comment: the first two functions are the same!

Answer (score 4):

The issue was probably caused by the length of the function name.

So, if the name is:

```
myFunctionsFromWorksWithCustumersTiggersTests
```

change for a shorter name, like:

```
WorkWithCustumers
```

I hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks! From some playing around, it looks like function names have a max length of 64 characters.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error when trying to publish a function listening to a Cloud pub/sub, that began with numerical characters.

```
exports.nightly_pruning = functions.pubsub.topic('24hr-tick').onPublish((event) => { 
    ... 
});
```

Fixed it by simply changing the name:

```
exports.nightly_pruning = functions.pubsub.topic('nightly-tick').onPublish((event) => { 
    ... 
});
```

(Thanks to Nikolai Hegelstad above. I don't have the reputation to comment.)

Comment: I feel like this is a bit more noise, then an actual answer. You've basically just implemented Nikolai's solution. You should either edit their answer to include an example, or consider gaining enough reputation for a comment/upvote.

Comment: It's a genuine answer. I've considered gaining more reputation - and answering questions like this is the way to do so. I am just trying to add value where I can, and due to my current reputation (because I haven't spent a lot of time giving back to stack overflow, this was the only way I could).

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same error until i changed my function name from

> create_template_

to

> create_new_template

It might be that '_'(underscore) at the end of function name resulted in this error.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this because of the underscore at the start of the exports function name.  You can test it yourself by trying this:

```
exports._someLongNameWithUnderscore= functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
  return true;
});

exports.someLongNameWithoutUnderscore= functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
  return true;
});

exports.shortName= functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
  return true;
});
```

The one with the underscore at the start or end will fail with `HTTP:400` and the others will deploy.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you're using the wrong Node version. I just experienced that after setting my node version to 8.x while working on functions. Switched back to v10.x and the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody is still experiencing this, in my case solution was running `npm install -g firebase-tools` to update cli, and adding

```
"engines": {
  "node": "8"
}
```

to package.json

Answer (score 0):

My issue with the same error message was that Cloud Functions' pubsub doesn't seem to support topics with names beginning with numeral characters.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to point out as well that the linter will reject line breaks on listener declaration, ie:

```
exporst.myFunc = functions.firestore
.document('collection/{uid}')
.onEvent(...)
```

which the linter doesnt help much and is not covered in documentation (as usual)